# could not convert string to float'.'

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I generated 2 columns in python, I transformed them in an np array, and managed to save them in a new file.

```
fi = np.array([co,pred[40]])
fi=fi.T
np.savetxt("Pred_40.dat", fi, delimiter=" ")
```

now I want to create an internal function that reads my new file. which I did but I got an error telling me: could not convert string to float'.'

```
def open_vmodel(vmodel_file,n_lag):
  list_ = []
  index = []
  vargplot = open(vmodel_file)
  for i in range(n_lag):
      dm = vargplot.readline()
      list_.append(list(map(float,dm))) 
  result = pd.DataFrame(list_)
  result.columns = ['Lag Distance','Variogram Value']
  istart = 0

      
  return pd.DataFrame(result)
```

```
vmodel_df = open_vmodel("Pred_40.dat",n_lag=1)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate more? what's `co`. what's the shape and content dtype of `fi`

Comment: Hi John, I just add them to my question, thanks

Comment: The error says that some where in a `dm` line there's a "bare" '.' character.  You/we need to look at the file, the lines that get read as `dm`.

Comment: 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+01 5.626957416534423828e-01
2.000000000000000000e+01 8.429691195487976074e-01
3.000000000000000000e+01 9.505254626274108887e-01
4.000000000000000000e+01 9.935916662216186523e-01
5.000000000000000000e+01 1.007314443588256836e+00

Comment: they are separated i  2 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use `dm = vargplot.readline().replace(".","")` ? There is a dot, so maybe it will fix your problem.

Comment: i tried , I got : could not convert string to float: ','

Comment: dm = vargplot.readline().replace(".","").replace(",","")

Comment: Try this also please

Comment: could not convert string to float: 'e' cause when i saved the values got 5.62695e-01

Comment: Then What about use regex? Can you use 
dm = vargplot.readline()
dm = re.findall("\d+\.\d+",dm) ?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.000000000000000000e+00'

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the line `list(map(float, dm))` is wrong. It tries to parse each character of dm as a number, so when it tries to parse '.' as a number it fails. Maybe try something like `list(map(float, dm.split()))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a problem with localization, as some regions use comma instead of dot for decimal places. When you are casting to float, one of the numbers might be like `0.2` and Python might expect `0,2`.

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC,"C")
```

This will set the number format to the standard one, which will accept `0.5` instead of `0,5`

Comment: @KarimMokdad  I'm pretty sure the line `list(map(float, dm))` is wrong. It tries to parse each character of dm as a number, so when it tries to parse '.' as a number it fails. Maybe try something like
`list(map(float, dm.split()))`

Comment: I managed to change it but with the same concept and it working thanks

Answer (score 0):

With a sample of your file (from the comment):

```
In [218]: txt="""0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 
     ...: 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 
     ...: 1.000000000000000000e+01 5.626957416534423828e-01"""

In [220]: txt = txt.splitlines()
In [221]: txt
Out[221]: 
['0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 ',
 '0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 ',
 '1.000000000000000000e+01 5.626957416534423828e-01']
```

Your map iterates on all characters of a line:

```
In [222]: list(map(float, txt[0]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-222-47473c6c14f7>", line 1, in <module>
    list(map(float, txt[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'

In [223]: list(txt[0])[:10]
Out[223]: ['0', '.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

But if you first split the line on space, as recommended by https://stackoverflow.com/a/66678555/901925

```
In [224]: list(map(float, txt[0].split()))
Out[224]: [0.0, 0.0]
```

Or for several lines (I like list comprehension better than map):

```
In [225]: res = []
     ...: for dm in txt:
     ...:     res.append([float(i) for i in dm.split()])
     ...: 
In [226]: res
Out[226]: [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [10.0, 0.5626957416534424]]
```